# Collapsing a Twitter bootstrap drop-down menu as soon as a menu item is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap drop-down menu with AJAX links(i.e links with `data-remote="true"`). When I click on a link, the menu remains open until the AJAX call is complete. Is there a way to collapse the menu as soon as a user clicks on a link?

Here is a jsFiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rGV2j/) to demonstrate the problem. (Please overlook the fact that I am freezing the thread in the sample code. I wanted to simulate scenario with few lines of code.)

**Note:** I am using Twitter bootstrap v 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a single-page site I was building recently. You can close the nav on click of its links with the following:

```
$('.nav a').click(function () {
    $(".nav-collapse").collapse("hide")
});
```

More info can be found in the [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), see the Method section.

Comment: This hides the link which is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to exclude the dropdown toggle

```
$(".nav a[class!='dropdown-toggle']").click(function () {
 $(".navbar-collapse").collapse("hide")
}):
```